# making a color selector with multiple selects java

Tags: java, user-interface, colors, rgb

I want to make a GUI object that will somehow function like a slider
this slider has values that have the rage of rgb int and also show graphically show the color spectrum parallel to the slider
so it should mixture of two pictures below

**Spectrum**
[image: spectrum]
<sub>(source: [whiterockscience.com](http://www.whiterockscience.com/scan2mcnp/images/SpectrumBar.jpg))</sub>

**Slider**
[image: slider]
<sub>(source: [dreamincode.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/post-73490-1235704974.jpg))</sub>

and finally this graphical object should have the ability to be chosen multiple times so its quite different than actual slider hence the ticks for rgb int values  .it means that the user can click on for example 4 different parts of spectrum and then the code will store the rgb int value of each click to an array
how can I make something like this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not, try, then come back with any problems you have. If you're totally stumped, tell us what you want, maybe with a mockup of how it should look, and we might be able to help.

Comment: yes I have, but this is a mixture of two different graphical components and I dont know how to design a new one as Im quite new to java .
I'm using this data (the rgb int ) to draw graphs and painting lines with those values 
I've figured out other parts but I don't know how to do this part

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Your links were replaced with the images themselves, which tends to be a better practice than linking images. It's probably too involved for someone new to Java to be doing; I haven't used Swing in the past year or so but if I recall it's quite annoying to make new components with custom rendering. Is there a workaround you can use instead?

Comment: I couldnt link because of low reputation so that was why It was edited :)
the ultimate goal is to make a grapher than gets a mathematical expression like ADD(MUL(x,y) , z) ) and then asks the user to choose a variable as the color variable(and values for other variables) so that variable will have the value of that color the user chooses .so when the user clicks 3 different colors with values 3,49 ,50 the grapher will draw three lines that each have one of those values and is painted by that value's color

Comment: Why not have three separate sliders? It would certainly be easier, and if the order of the colors matters (as it seems to) it would also be less ambiguous. Try that and if you have specific problems, ask about those, rather than asking for code.

Comment: thats a good idea  but rgb int value isn't the problem I have to make some form of graphical object that can be clicked multiple times and should graphically show color spectrum
and thats what I don't know how to make a interactive color spectrum that can be clicked and the event handler then stores the rgb values of clicks in some field

Comment: Why? Having three separate ones would be easier to make and simpler to use. (This is also getting a bit off-topic, so once the link pops up, let's move it to chat)

Comment: low reputation I cant chat 
by the way three sliders is a good idea but the professor has said to make this multi-clickable color spectrum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JColorChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html) is probably what you want in most instances it's easy to implement and easy to use. Is what you're wanting this?

[image: Slider + Spectrum]

If that's what you're looking for I think your best bet would be to draw images on a JPanel through paintComponents. Perhaps draw an image of a slider and draw a spectrum underneath it and get mouseListeners added to handle events when you have touched the spectrum picture or slider portion. To get a slider to grab the right color it would be something like this.

Another point of information that would be useful is to go into paint and check out how that slider works and see the RGB values and how they change.

Comment: Go ahead and attempt if you really want this more than anything and post your code when you run into problems in a new question.